# Add location of cell to SUM formula

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to add the location of a cell into a SUM formula?

I have the following For Each ... Next loop, but instead of merely counting the number of cells that contain a value of 1, I would like to add the specific location of such a cell into a SUM formula.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("I3:DC70")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 1 Then Range("DF4").Value = Range("DF4").Value + 1
Next cell
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Would you not get the same results using countif?

Comment: This is my first project in VBA, so I don't know. I'll check on it. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it and it does give me the same result, but I need the specific location of each cell for another layer in the project.

Comment: What should that look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `.Find` and `.FindNext`. You can read about it [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). This approach is much faster than looping when you have a large dataset.

Here is something that I wrote quickly. Please amend it to suit your needs.

```
Sub Find_Cells_Which_Has_My_Damn_String()
    Dim WhatToFind As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range, rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Set here what to find
    WhatToFind = "1"

    '~~> Set this to the relevant range
    Set SearchRange = ws.Cells

    Set aCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=WhatToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        Set rng = aCell
        Do
            Set aCell = SearchRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set rng = Union(rng, aCell)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng.Address Else _
    MsgBox "No cells were found containing " & WhatToFind
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]